# why need p=NULL when releasing pointer type of object in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p)              {if(NULL != p) {delete p; p = NULL;}}
```

if need p=null after deleting p?

if need, why need it?

Comment: presumably so that a second attempt won't try to delete it a second time....!

Comment: Only bad code needs to set a pointer to NULL after `delete`ing it.

Comment: @Praetorian: that's why it's called SAFE_DELETE !  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double delete/free is not permitted, the following codes results a "double free error" during runtime:

- `delete p; delete p;`
- `free(p); free(p);`

but deleting/freeing a NULL point is OK:

- `delete NULL;` // does nothing
- `free(NULL);` // does nothing

you don't have to check a pointer is null or not before deleting/freeing it, C/C++ standards permit NULL to be passed into delete/free. so it's not a "must" to check if a pointer is null or not before free/delete.
this, your `SAFE_DELETE(P)` can safely be simplified to

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) do { delete p; p = NULL; } while (0);
```

setting a pointer to NULL after free/delete is to make sure you don't free/delete it in some later time.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *needed*. It's just an added security. Deleting the content renders the data invalid. If you try to dereference `p` after having deleted it, you expose yourself to undefined behavior. By setting it to `NULL`, you are clearly indicating that this pointer is not valid anymore (and can check that easily with something like `if (p != NULL) {...}`, whereas you cannot check whether or not the data has been freed).